# How to make a CURL call to Dropbox API using Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, dropbox-api

I am new to Meteor.js and want to make my web app work with Dropbox Core API. I am not able to wrap my head around making API calls using the HTTP package in Meteor.js

How can I make a call in Meteor which is similar to the Curl call below :

```
curl https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>"
```

I wish to get list of files in the directory but for now I am stuck with the Authentical Token.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the HTTP package you mentioned

Add it with

```
meteor add http
```

Then to use it (server side). This should produce exactly what the `curl` request above gives out.

```
var result = HTTP.get("https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info", {
             headers: {
                 Authorization: "Bearer <access token>"
             }
});

console.log(result.content)
console.log(result.data) //<< JSON form (if api reports application/json as the content-type header
```

Comment: You can also use https://atmospherejs.com/webstudiopro/curl

meteor add webstudiopro:curl

Comment: What should be the header if i have a username and a token ID?