# how to execute curl command in meteor serverside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, meteor

I have a curl command which i want to execute from the serverside of meteor and then retrieve the result.

```
 curl -k htts://<username>:<usertoken>@<url>/api/json?pretty=true
```

Is it possible to do this? are there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: May this helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117689/how-to-make-a-curl-call-to-dropbox-api-using-meteor-js

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: in this `headers: {
                 Authorization: "Bearer <access token>"
             }' bearer should be replaced with username?

Comment: I have a jenkin url which has authentication, using the username and token in curl command i got the jenkins details in json format in terminal. But i want the same to be done in meteor serverside and retrieve the data for further operations.

Comment: if you just want to make http request, the HTTP package is sufficient. Rather if you want to invoke shell commands, read this. https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2015/02/26/meteor-run-shell-command-at-server-side/